# OneDrive SMB access

Tags: windows, onedrive, smb, cloud-storage

Is there a way to access **OneDrive** via **SMB**? I mean, for creating a local or network drive in Windows for accessing the cloud storage through. Maybe through other layers offered by another software? **WebDAV** is unacceptable because data direct access is needed (for example, for database file). If there is no any possible way for this, then suggest other cloud service(s) with feature specified, that could offer about 15 GiB of free space. Or with small price per first ≈30 GiB.

Comment: Is there a reason to insist on SMB ?

Comment: Is my clarification about direct data access isn't enough? WebDAV copies entire file for reading operation and for writing one.

Comment: Asking for specific commercial product suggestions is not generally allowed here.

Comment: "Direct Access" in OneDrive terminology means permission to access your OneDrive location or SharePoint library, not much more. You can't dictate to OneDrive an access method.

Comment: Not just **direct access** but **direct data access**. I mean, read or write just specified intervals of file attributes, without necessity of copying entire file for that.

Comment: You could mount a OneDrive share on a PC with almost any OS, and access that OneDrive folder from other machines as a SMB share *on that PC*.

Comment: The purpose of the job is to *move* (actually, to create) data from local storage to the cloud, because all the data is larger than any local storage, and the data must be available for access (reading and writing) anytime 24/7. Files are BIG (up to several dozens of GiB).

Comment: @green It sounds like you want a cloud database, not a file in the cloud. OneDrive does not offer that service. Specific recommendations are off-topic for Super User.

Comment: @green Dozens of GB is not large for a database. Have you considered having a machine on-premises for it? That way, if the internet connection fails it is still available, and backups can be taken off-site for if the site burns down.

Comment: It's not about conventional databases. So, DB services are mostly not suitable. I need just to store several big files, that could be randomly accessed (by relatively small portions of them), as if they are being stored on local/network drive. I have no such big local storage, and some other reasons apply.

Comment: @green "I have no such big local storage" - could you buy a NAS device? It might be that you need one that offers [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI), and the services of a consultant to set it up correctly, which really shouldn't take very long, if you're not confident in trying it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long and short: No. No, OneDrive does not support SMB or anything like that.

Now, you could certainly create some “proxy” that does the translation. BUT there is a bit of a problem with the type of access you want: Even with an actual SMB file share on the local network, it would be a *really bad* idea to put a database’s backend storage on it. Performance would suffer a lot from access latency, especially because OneDrive is unlikely to be optimized for that.

There’s yet another big problem: OneDrive (and many other object storage services!) does not support updating only parts of a file. Instead, a new version must be uploaded in its entirety.

But wait, there’s more: Concurrent access to the file would only be possible if it is entirely read-only, because reliable synchronization of writes is not available.

---

Yet again, I must insist you look into Software as a Service offers for databases. Even if you say it’s “not about conventional databases”, these offers do exist, lots of them for all sorts of database engines. Only a single database service can provide consistent high-performance access.

---

If you truly want, managed block storage services with SMB access exist. Microsoft Azure Storage Accounts, Hetzner Storage Box and Strato HiDrive come to mind. Keep in mind that you want one that is hosted close to you, to minimize latency.